# split screen to more than two

Tags: screen, split

if you use (super + right/left arrow) it will move the window to the right or left side of the screen and you can split the entire of your screen for two windows.
is there any way to do split the screen for more than two windows?
for example I want to split my screen for 4 windows.
how can i do it?
I'm using ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 8):

You can use [ShellTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/657/shelltile/) Gnome Extension.

[image]

Comment: Hey. thanks it's pretty good. I wish i could have set keyboard shortcuts for them. I know it has 4 but for other positions it doesn't have. other than that it's pretty good.

Comment: Thank you so much for your shared